# Как узнать ширину блока с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript

Допустим у меня есть блок с длиной и шириной ***100px***, и с границами ***2px***.

Как мне узнать точную ширину блока , то есть без границ и прочих атрибутов?

Пробовал свойства ***`offserWidth, clientWidth, scrollWidth`***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const element = document.querySelector('div');

console.log('clientWidth = content + padding:', element.clientWidth);
console.log('offsetWidth = content + padding + border:',element.offsetWidth);

const styles = getComputedStyle(element);

console.log('clientWidth - paddingRight - paddingLeft = content:', element.clientWidth - parseInt(styles.paddingRight) - parseInt(styles.paddingLeft));
console.log('width = content:', parseInt(styles.width));
```

```css
body {
  height: 230px;
}
.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  
  padding: 40px;
  border: 10px solid rgba(200, 100, 0, 0.9);
  
  background-color: rgba(200, 100, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 40px rgba(200, 100, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class='element'></div>
```

Comment: Есть еще `getBoundingClientRect()` )